# How to let users upload multiple files with specific extensions in PHP?

Tags: php, image, file-upload, upload

This is a piece of code I stumbled upon which allows users to upload multiple files to your website. It works perfectly however how do I make it so that the type of files uploaded are limited?

For example, users can upload any files they want (.txt, .php, .png, .jpg, etc) but lets say I only want them to upload (.html, .png, .jpg), how would I do that?

```
$target_dir = "";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);


//Loop through each file
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']); $i++) {
//Get the temp file path
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$i];

//Make sure we have a filepath
if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
//Setup our new file path
$newFilePath = "" . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$i];

//Upload the file into the temp dir
if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

  //Handle other code here

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a list of allowed file extentions, then check if the uploaded file is valid

```
$target_dir = "";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$allowed = array("html", "jpg", "png");

//Loop through each file
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']); $i++) {

    //Get the temp file path
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $filename = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$i];

    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!in_array($ext, $allowed)){
        continue;
    }

    //Make sure we have a filepath
    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
    //Setup our new file path
    $newFilePath = "" . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$i];

    //Upload the file into the temp dir
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

        //Handle other code here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### try this

```
$file_type = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']; //returns the mimetype
$allowed = array("image/png", "image/jpg");
if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {
  $error_message = 'Only jpg, gif are allowed.';
  $error = 'yes';
}
```

Even in form page you can make that

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" accept="image/x-png, image/jpeg" />
```